# How to exhaustively build all graphs that respect certain boundaries?

Tags: graph-theory

So I hail from a background in chemistry and I love me some graph theory... At least in theory. Except for some mild applications for chemoinformatics, I haven't really delved deep into this branch of mathematics. But anyway, my interests revolve around representing molecules as graphs. Nodes are atoms and (undirected) edges are bonds (notice that multiple edges can connect two nodes in molecular graphs). This representation ignores the 3D reality of a molecular geometry but it captures the topology of a system of chemical bonds quite appropriately. Some molecules are so small and connected that you can reconstruct its 3D structure pretty easily from its topology alone, and those are of special interest to me.

In fact, these small molecules are of *such interest* to me that I have started a software aiming to generate them in a systematic fashion and graph theory seemed to me the most suited theoretical framework on which to cast my idea, so that I may program it with a suitable programming language.

[image: Some small molecules and their graph-theoretical representation]

As you can see from the figure, the graphs that represent the small molecules I am interested in have different types of nodes and the potential for multiple edges to form between each node. There are two rules that determine whether a given graph  is *valid*:

1. Nodes of each type have a maximum degree they are allowed to have;
2. No pair of nodes may have more than three edges between them;
3. The graph cannot be disjoint.

For a given number of nodes and a given set of types of nodes, I would like to know if there exists an algorithm to create an exhaustive set of every valid graph that could be created. Or at least information on algorithm that do *almost* that.

I tried doing this with python's networkx module using the configuration_model algorithm, but it generates random graphs that respects the maximum degree clause. That is not enough and I don't know precisely  how to expand on what networkx gave me to write de appropriate algorithm.